# LXC endless restating loop

Tags: 16.04, restart, network-bridge, lxd

**(Please see below update 1, 2 and 3)**

Today I updated the host system then after a reboot the LXD daemon do not start.

It gives the error

```
failed to create listening socket for 10.104.52.1: Address already in use
```

What can I do?

I have:

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- lxd   2.16        3346  canonical  - (snap version)

The command I used to start

```
sudo systemctl start snap.lxd.daemon.service
```

Extract from syslog:

```
Aug 15 20:05:52 s4 lxc[23200]: cmd.go:118: DEBUG: restarting into "/snap/core/current/usr/bin/snap"
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application lxd.daemon.
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 /usr/bin/snap[23219]: cmd.go:118: DEBUG: restarting into "/snap/core/current/usr/bin/snap"
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: => Preparing the system
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: ==> Preparing a clean copy of /run
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: ==> Preparing a clean copy of /etc
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: ==> Setting up ceph configuration
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: ==> Setting up LVM configuration
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: ==> Escaping the systemd cgroups                                                                                                                     
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: ==> Escaping the systemd process resource limits                                                                                                     
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: ==> Enabling unprivileged containers kernel support                                                                                                  
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: => Starting LXCFS                                                                                                                                    
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: => Starting LXD                                                                                                                                      
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 kernel: [  767.318344] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored                                                            
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: lvl=warn msg="CGroup memory swap accounting is disabled, swap limits will be ignored." t=2017-08-15T18:06:12+0000                                    
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]: hierarchies:                                                                                                                                         
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   0: fd:   5: memory                                                                                                                                 
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   1: fd:   6: blkio                                                                                                                                  
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   2: fd:   7: hugetlb                                                                                                                                
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   3: fd:   8: cpuset                                                                                                                                 
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   4: fd:   9: devices
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   5: fd:  10: net_cls,net_prio
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   6: fd:  11: freezer
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   7: fd:  12: pids
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   8: fd:  13: perf_event
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:   9: fd:  14: cpu,cpuacct
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 snap[23219]:  10: fd:  15: name=systemd
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 avahi-daemon[1986]: Withdrawing address record for 10.104.52.1 on lxdbr0.
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 avahi-daemon[1986]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lxdbr0.IPv4 with address 10.104.52.1.
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 avahi-daemon[1986]: Interface lxdbr0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 named[2579]: no longer listening on 10.104.52.1#53
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 avahi-daemon[1986]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface lxdbr0.IPv4 with address 10.104.52.1.
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 avahi-daemon[1986]: New relevant interface lxdbr0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 avahi-daemon[1986]: Registering new address record for 10.104.52.1 on lxdbr0.IPv4.
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 named[2579]: listening on IPv4 interface lxdbr0, 10.104.52.1#53
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 dnsmasq[23351]: failed to create listening socket for 10.104.52.1: Address already in use
Aug 15 20:06:12 s4 dnsmasq[23351]: FAILED to start up
```

**=========== UPDATE ==================================**

After a fresh start from power on the LXC daemon enter in an endless restarting loop.
Tried to stop the daemon; but it ends in an error state.
Here the transcript:

```
sysop@s4:~$ lxc list
LXD socket not found; is LXD installed and running?
sysop@s4:~$ sudo systemctl stop snap.lxd.daemon.service
[sudo] password di sysop: 
sysop@s4:~$ sudo systemctl status snap.lxd.daemon.service
● snap.lxd.daemon.service - Service for snap application lxd.daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.lxd.daemon.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since mer 2017-08-16 06:26:41 CEST; 33s ago
Process: 32064 ExecStop=/usr/bin/snap run --command=stop lxd.daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 29801 ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap run lxd.daemon (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 29801 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

ago 16 06:26:39 s4 snap[29526]: action=shutdown created=2017-08-06T10:45:02+0000 ephemeral=false lvl=eror msg="Failed shutting down container" name=liferaybase t=2017-08-16T04:26:39
ago 16 06:26:39 s4 snap[29526]: lvl=warn msg="Unable to update backup.yaml at this time." name=cybersec t=2017-08-16T04:26:39+0000
ago 16 06:26:39 s4 snap[29526]: lvl=warn msg="Unable to update backup.yaml at this time." name=liferaybase t=2017-08-16T04:26:39+0000
ago 16 06:26:39 s4 snap[29526]: lvl=warn msg="Unable to update backup.yaml at this time." name=servizi t=2017-08-16T04:26:39+0000
ago 16 06:26:39 s4 snap[29526]: lvl=warn msg="Unable to update backup.yaml at this time." name=db-server t=2017-08-16T04:26:39+0000
ago 16 06:26:40 s4 snap[29526]: lvl=warn msg="Unable to update backup.yaml at this time." name=icons t=2017-08-16T04:26:40+0000
ago 16 06:26:40 s4 snap[32064]: => Stopping LXCFS
ago 16 06:26:41 s4 systemd[1]: Stopped Service for snap application lxd.daemon.
ago 16 06:26:41 s4 systemd[1]: snap.lxd.daemon.service: Unit entered failed state.
ago 16 06:26:41 s4 systemd[1]: snap.lxd.daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sysop@s4:~$
```

How can I clear the error state?

**============================= UPDATE 2 =================================**

Output in syslog of "sudo systemctl start snap.lxd.daemon.service"

```
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application lxd.daemon.
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 /usr/bin/snap[25736]: cmd.go:189: DEBUG: restarting into "/snap/core/current/usr/bin/snap"
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: => Preparing the system
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: ==> Preparing a clean copy of /run
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: ==> Preparing a clean copy of /etc
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: ==> Setting up ceph configuration
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: ==> Setting up LVM configuration
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: ==> Escaping the systemd cgroups
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: ==> Escaping the systemd process resource limits
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: ==> Enabling unprivileged containers kernel support
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: => Starting LXCFS
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: => Starting LXD
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 kernel: [ 1154.222272] cgroup: new mount options do not match the existing superblock, will be ignored
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: lvl=warn msg="CGroup memory swap accounting is disabled, swap limits will be ignored." t=2017-08-16T09:09:44+0000
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: => LXD is ready
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]: hierarchies:
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   0: fd:   5: freezer
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   1: fd:   6: devices
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   2: fd:   7: memory
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   3: fd:   8: pids
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   4: fd:   9: perf_event
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   5: fd:  10: hugetlb
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   6: fd:  11: cpuset
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   7: fd:  12: blkio
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   8: fd:  13: cpu,cpuacct
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:   9: fd:  14: net_cls,net_prio
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 snap[25736]:  10: fd:  15: name=systemd
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 avahi-daemon[1993]: Withdrawing address record for 10.104.52.1 on lxdbr0.
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 avahi-daemon[1993]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface lxdbr0.IPv4 with address 10.104.52.1.
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 avahi-daemon[1993]: Interface lxdbr0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 named[2591]: no longer listening on 10.104.52.1#53
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 avahi-daemon[1993]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface lxdbr0.IPv4 with address 10.104.52.1.
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 avahi-daemon[1993]: New relevant interface lxdbr0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 avahi-daemon[1993]: Registering new address record for 10.104.52.1 on lxdbr0.IPv4.
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 named[2591]: listening on IPv4 interface lxdbr0, 10.104.52.1#53
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 named[2591]: network unreachable resolving 'ubuntu.com/DS/IN': 2001:503:a83e::2:30#53
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 named[2591]: network unreachable resolving 'ubuntu.com/DS/IN': 2001:503:eea3::30#53
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 dnsmasq[25868]: failed to create listening socket for 10.104.52.1: Address already in use
Aug 16 11:09:44 s4 dnsmasq[25868]: FAILED to start up
Aug 16 11:09:45 s4 dnsmasq[25869]: failed to create listening socket for 10.104.52.1: Address already in use
Aug 16 11:09:45 s4 dnsmasq[25869]: FAILED to start up
Aug 16 11:09:45 s4 dnsmasq[25870]: failed to create listening socket for 10.104.52.1: Address already in use
Aug 16 11:09:45 s4 dnsmasq[25870]: FAILED to start up
Aug 16 11:09:46 s4 dnsmasq[25871]: failed to create listening socket for 10.104.52.1: Address already in use
Aug 16 11:09:46 s4 dnsmasq[25871]: FAILED to start up
```

From here it enter the endless loop and never starts

**==================== UPDATE 3 ===================================**

I have a physical machine with the endlesse restart loop error and a virtual machine that restarts correctly.

In the phisical machine(with the error - taken during the loop):

```
sysop@s4:~$ sudo brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
lxdbr0          8000.fe049a888031       no              veth7KVBSH
                                                        vethFPOTVD
                                                        vethRA1QON
                                                        vethXPQLPC
                                                        vethYWVLD4
lxdbr1          8000.fe503c909805       no              vethGDM55D
virbr1          8000.525400d8609d       yes             virbr1-nic
```

In the virtual machine (which restarts correctly):

```
sysop@vx00:~$ sudo brctl show
[sudo] password di sysop: 
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
lxdbr0          8000.fe4f7f04c603       no              veth13QLME
                                                        veth8VLGTS
                                                        vethK17EY7
                                                        vethMBSAPN
                                                        vethX7TJ8L
lxdbr1          8000.fec3f10606ce       no              vethOXYX5G
virbr1          8000.fe5400ffa6aa       yes             vnet1
```

Can this be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Read the message "failed to create listening socket for 10.104.52.1: Address already in use"

so choose another ip address, 10.104.52.2 or some such

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, i mean that the address already in use is issued for every container and the addresses are the addresses assigned and working before the reboot. Please read the question update

Answer (score 0):

Replying to myself
**SOLVED**

I installed bind9 on the same machine and this takes precedence on dnsmasq

In the endless loop status:

```
sysop@s4:~/script$ sudo netstat -anlp | grep -w LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5900          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4888/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5145/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5902          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5287/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5903          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5457/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3916/perl       
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 10.104.52.1:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 192.168.66.1:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 192.168.33.1:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 192.168.99.1:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 192.168.13.128:53       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.21:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.22:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.20:53         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2593/sshd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3910/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN      3916/perl       
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2593/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      20214/named     
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      3910/master
```

Stopping bind9 lxc starts correctly and I have

```
sysop@s4:~/script$ sudo netstat -anlp | grep -w LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5900          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4888/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5145/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5902          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5287/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5903          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5457/qemu-system-x8
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3916/perl       
tcp        0      0 10.0.1.1:53             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20457/dnsmasq   
tcp        0      0 10.104.52.1:53          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      20402/dnsmasq   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2593/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3910/master     
tcp6       0      0 :::10000                :::*                    LISTEN      3916/perl       
tcp6       0      0 fe80::fc50:3cff:fe90:53 :::*                    LISTEN      20457/dnsmasq   
tcp6       0      0 fe80::20b2:ceff:fe25:53 :::*                    LISTEN      20402/dnsmasq   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      2593/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      3910/master
```